# Asterisk record a .wav file and save a same file name of call file

Tags: asterisk

I make a script that automatic create a .call file and auto-move to /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/, im done with that but in recording
i want to save a .wav file same as .call file

FILE

> testcalls150.call

EXTENTIONS.CONF

> [outgoingcall]
>   exten => s,1,Answer( )
>   exten=>s,2,Record(/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/**${CALLFILENAME(name)}**/${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},GMT-8,%m%d%y-%H:%M:%S)}.wav,0,0,qxk)

OUTPUT:

> in /var/spool/asterisk/tmp/**testcalls150(date-time).wav**

Thanks in Advance,
OAcebes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

You need create call file with

```
Set: callfile_name=testcalls150.call
```

After that you able do in dialplan:

```
exten=>s,2,Record(/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/${callfile_name}${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},GMT-8,%m%d%y-%H:%M:%S)}.wav,0,0,qxk)
```

Note, when creating your call files you also have check that asterisk running and number of files in /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing is LOW. becuase can be situation when you always adding files and asterisk not able process same rate. Result will be system mailfunction after 2000-3000 files in folder.